# How to create two exe files with one nsis script?

Tags: nsis

I have to create two exe files with one nsis script. One contains zip file as a full pack and other does not contain the zip file. Im setting a parameter in perl file which is calling my nsis script and using the parameter in nsis script. Problem is with the "outfile". Unable to check the condition.

Example:

passing parameter as $FULL_PKG =1 (with zip file), =0 (without zip file)
    name "PKG"
    Strcmp ${FULL_PKG} "1" 0 1
    outfile "FULLPKG.exe"
    outfile "PKG.exe"'

```
ERROR: command not valid outside section or function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes like `Outfile` can not be changed at run-time (Code in sections and functions)

You can create defines by using [/D with makensis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html): `makensis /DNOZIP yourscript.nsi` and then check for this define:

```
!ifdef NOZIP
Outfile nozip.exe
!else
Outfile withzip.exe
!endif
...
Section
!ifndef NOZIP
File foo.zip ;Extract the zip file
!endif
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is also working (maybe it wasn't available in 2012):

```
!if ${FULL_PKG} == 1
    OutFile "FULLPKG.exe"
!else
    OutFile "PKG.exe"
!endif
```